# Android APP and mysql interact

Tags: android, mysql

I've got a site where i put my events, i want to build an application (for android first ) that will display my events, as my site does.
in my site i use a MySQL database 
now i'm learning to programming android app, what's the best way to do what i want?

i didn't try nothing because, i don't know how to do, and i'm studying it by myself.

```html
function inserisci_div() {

   /* dichiariamo alcune importanti variabili per collegarci al database */
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "bestparty";
$DBpass = "";
$DBName = "my_bestparty";

/* specifichiamo il nome della nostra tabella */
$table = "Dati";

/* Connettiamoci al database */
mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server");
@mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Impossibile connettersi al database $DBName");



/* impostiamo la query ORDINANDO IN ORDINE DECRESCENTE PER ID */
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM `Dati` ORDER BY Data DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

this is the PHP file that i use on my site to connect my php page to my DB

it's only for having an idea, because i'm newer on android programming.
Thank you, and sorry for my bad English..

Comment: Did you try anything? Oh, I see, nothing. Do you want a link to the beginners guide?

Comment: i want to know if there is a best way to do what i want, i want to know if it is hard to do, and if there is, a guide to do that.. thank you very much

Comment: The best way is to read books first, than ask questions if something is not clear for you

Comment: Is there a best way? - No. - Is it hard to do? - Depends on. - Is there a guide? - Of course!

Comment: Read this blog post first then you will understand.http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to convert your php data (mostly an array) to a JSON and echo it as response to a http request...

echo json_encode($myArray);

Than on Android, you need to read about ListView Adapter, JSONArray/Object, also about AsyncTask and HttpClient...

Thats the keywords to google for.

You will need to fetch your data responded from you php with a HTTP GET, or POST in an AsyncTask, then put it into an JSONArray which will be the datasource for yor ListAdapter, that provides the data to your ListView that shows it...